# Need ASN.1 files for SCCP (SS7)

Tags: asn.1, ss7

I'm working on an application that will generate SS7 Protocols specifically SCCP,MAP. Hence, I need the ASN.1 files run through an ASN1c compiler to generate C struct codes.

I've managed to find the MAP ASN.1 files on 3gpp.org but unable to find ASN.1 files for SCCP. So, I did a little bit of research and it seems that I need to decode SCCP messages. But I have absolutely no idea where to start and decode them. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you solve that eventually? I'm stuck exactly on the same place, and the specs are somewhat cryptic

Answer (score 0):

SCCP, either in ITU and ANSI recommendations, is not ASN.1 encoded. Only protocols over TCAP (so at presentation and application levels) are ASN.1 encoded.
If you are dealing with ITU flavor of SCCP, you could have a look at ITU Q.713 recommendation to get an idea of formats and codes for this protocol.